# Normalizing Ordinal Predictors When Treating as Continuous in Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, normalization, ordinal-data

There are a variety of questions about ordinal predictors in regression analyses. I am interested in logistic regression and specifically whether I need to normalize ordinal data after deciding to treat it as continuous. Should I normalize the data using the standard score (i.e. (x - xmean)/std deviation)? I think it makes sense to do so but are there other, better methods for normalizing ordinal data when treating it is continuous in a logistic regression equation?

Comment: Since ordinal data are, by definition, *not numbers*, you first have to address a more fundamental question: exactly how do you propose to encode the data numerically? That matters far more than any subsequent normalizations or transformations.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about these ordinal predictors... Are they from a Likert scale? Are they all thought to be measuring the same thing or different things? How many predictors/levels are there?

Comment: The choice to standardize vs. not standardize won't have an effect on the regression coefficient, FWIW.